# How do I get the current and last greater value in one sequence in a table?

Tags: mysql

I have an InnoDB table 'plant_alarm' in MySQL with columns

```
`plant_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
'alarm_code' var(20) NOT NULL,
`time` int(20) NOT NULL, [...]
```

so there can be multiple timestamps per id and multiple ids per timestamp along with the alarm_code.

I'm trying to set up a query where I get entries plus the last greater time for entry in sequence if it exists, so it should return e.g.:

```
Time    Plant id    Alarm Code
00:00      10             RUN
00:00      11             RUN
00:01      10             RUN
00:01      11             RUN
00:02      10             STOP
00:02      11             RUN
00:03      10             STOP
00:03      11             STOP
00:04      10             RUN
00:04      11             STOP
00:05      10             RUN
00:05      11             RUN
```

```
Alarm Start Time        Alarm End Time  |--|Plant id    Alarm Code
00:00 |------------------| 00:01             10            RUN
00:00 |------------------|00:02              11            RUN
00:02 |------------------| 00:03         10            STOP
00:03 |------------------| 00:04         11            STOP
00:04 |------------------| NULL              10            RUN
00:05 |------------------| NULL              11            RUN
```

We have tried finding next time and minimum-maximum time by grouping the data via plant id and alarm code but it returns only 1 alarm for the whole day & is very slow.

Below is the MySQL query we figured out till now:

```
SELECT 
    temp_plant_id,
    temp_alarm_code, 
    temp_date_time, 
    (   SELECT 
            MIN(temp_date_time) 
        FROM 
            plant_alarm_data_temp sub 
        WHERE 
            sub.temp_plant_id = main.temp_plant_id 
            and sub.temp_alarm_code = main.temp_alarm_code 
            and sub.temp_date_time > main.temp_date_time
    ) as nxttime
FROM plant_alarm_data_temp AS main
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper solution is to create a trigger firing on INSERT which will convert each pair of Start/Stop events into a timeframe and add it to table TIME_FRAMES. The trigger will check:

- if there is an open interval in table TIME_FRAMES for the given alarm and plant (meaning TIME_FRAMES.alarm_stop IS NULL) - set the `alarm_stop` for this interval
- otherwise this is a new time interval - so create a record in table TIME_FRAMES with column ALARM_START equal to the time and set the given alarm code and plant ID

It will be **MUCH** easier for you to query for time intervals rather than points in time.

---

Meanwhile you can try the following query (which is not very efficient):

```
SELECT p1.time AS alarm_start, p2.time AS alarm_stop, p1.plant_id, p1.alarm_code
FROM
(SELECT (@row1 := @row1 + 1) AS rownum, time, alarm_code, plant_id 
FROM plant_alarm, (SELECT @row1 := 0) AS t1
ORDER BY plant_id,time) AS p1
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT (@row2 := @row2 + 1) AS rownum, time, alarm_code, plant_id 
FROM plant_alarm, (SELECT @row2 := 0) AS t2
ORDER BY plant_id,time) AS p2
ON p2.rownum = p1.rownum + 1
ORDER BY p1.plant_id, p1.time
```

Comment: I tried your query but it gives the same output as we are getting our query. 
<br/>The query is fetching start time and end time for each time. While we require the start time to be displayed once & then the End time should be displayed along with the start time upto the time it was consecutively there.

Comment: It seems like you will have to implement this algorithm in your application code rather than trying to solve it with SQL. SQL is great when working with sets but not so great when dealing with sequences/streams of data (especially with inter-dependencies between the rows of the result set)

Comment: We are trying to implement the algorithm too, but not able to do that. Could you please assist if there is anything in your mind?

Comment: You will need to create a state machine which will transition between states according to the sequence of the rows coming from your SQL query. So your first define in what order you need the events (each row is an event) and then define the rules for switching between the states of your state machine. One of the states will be the one which outputs your desired cumulative (because it represents a particular sequence of events) output.